# Hugo site, either local or on Netlify, doesn't detect my content folders

Tags: blogs, netlify, hugo

I have two content folders: one called "About" and the other one called "blog". It looks like this on the private github repo, where netfliy pulls the data and build:

[image]

I'm not entirely sure what's missing both locally and on netlify. Locally, the about folder doesn't turn in a section, but the markdown page shows up. On Netfliy, no post at all shows up, and no section can be seen.

I'm using the [simplog theme](https://themes.gohugo.io/themes/simplog/).

config.toml looks like this

```
baseURL = "[redacted]"
languageCode = "pt-br"
title = "My New Hugo Site"
theme = "simplog"
author = "Tet"
description = "[redacted]"

[params]
    colorTheme = "default"
```

Here's how it looks on my machine:

[image]

Comment: Why would you want your about page to be at /about/about.html? Don't you mean /about/index.html?

Comment: I fixed this issue with a help from a friend. I forgot to update this post on StackOverflow. Repo and solution is here: https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/hugo-site-either-local-or-on-netlify-doesnt-detect-my-content-folders/33875/6